# How can I insert an image into state (React)

Tags: reactjs, image, state

How can I insert an image into state.

My goal is when I press a button - the image will display.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import img from "./img/img.jpg";

const ShowImage = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsVisible(!isVisible)}>
        {isVisible ? "Hide" : "Show"}
      </button>
      {isVisible && <img src={img} alt="img" />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShowImage;
```

Comment: Bad practise to use `() => setIsVisible(!isVisible)`. Need to change previous state.   `() => setIsVisible(prev => !prev)`.

Comment: for this case it is fine

Comment: No. When if you click too fast it's will be miss logic and image will be show when it's need to be hidden.

Comment: I now what are you talking about, in this case nothing will breaks, state will be either `true` or `false`